# How can I keep datatable headlines in one line?

Tags: css, html-table, scroll, datatables

In my datatable the headlines are in one line with the sort arrows.

[image]

But my datatables is scrollable and when I make my window smaller the headline jumps down.

[image]

I tried to fix this like this:

```
  .table th{
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
```

But it does not make a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `word-wrap: break-word;` you should go with `white-space: nowrap;`. That way white spaces inside the header cell won't be breaking.